using runserver in django runs all scripts but using daphne for production runs only asgi.py
I have a problem when i setup django for production
for some reason, when i use runserver it checks all the scripts and runs them all completely fine
but when i run it using daphne it ignores everything and starts the server immediately
here's the structure of my project
.
├── Dockerfile
├── chat
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── graph.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_alter_langchainhistorysession_id_and_more.py
│   │   ├── 0003_rename_collection_id_langchainembedding_collection.py
│   │   ├── 0004_alter_langchainembedding_id.py
│   │   ├── 0005_alter_langchainhistorysession_account_id.py
│   │   ├── 0006_alter_langchainhistorysession_chat_history.py
│   │   ├── 0007_langchainhistorysession_enabled.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── permissions.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── chatbot
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── data_worker
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils.py
├── db_init.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── graph.png
├── gunicorn_conf.py
├── manage.py
├── market_data.json
├── markets.csv
├── nginx
│   └── nginx.conf
├── prompt.txt
├── requirements.txt
└── wait-for-it.sh

asgi.py
"""
ASGI config for chatbot project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import socketio
import json

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'chatbot.settings')
cors_allowed_origins = list(json.loads(os.getenv("CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS")))
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins=cors_allowed_origins)
socketio_app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio, django_asgi_app)

application = socketio_app


so i developed the backend using py manage.py runserver and the supposed behaviour is that it runs the graph.py which uses data_worker to fetch some data related to the application and then starts the app
2024-06-04 10:03:07,415 [INFO ] [10944] Fetching market info
2024-06-04 10:03:07,651 [INFO ] [10944] Fetched market info
2024-06-04 10:03:08,295 [INFO ] [10944] Last news id: (1164386,)
2024-06-04 10:03:08,295 [INFO ] [10944] Total news fetched: 0
2024-06-04 10:03:08,295 [INFO ] [10944] No new news to add
2024-06-04 10:03:14,072 [INFO ] [10944] Fetched markets data in 5 seconds
2024-06-04 10:03:14,942 [INFO ] [10944] Market data fetching process finished
2024-06-04 10:03:16,285 [INFO ] [10944] HTTP Request: POST https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
2024-06-04 10:03:16,461 [INFO ] [10944] None
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 04, 2024 - 10:03:17
Django version 5.0.6, using settings 'chatbot.settings'
Starting ASGI/Daphne version 4.1.2 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
2024-06-04 10:03:17,031 [INFO ] [10944] HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2024-06-04 10:03:17,032 [INFO ] [10944] Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2024-06-04 10:03:17,033 [INFO ] [10944] Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000

now when i run daphne chatbot.asgi:application it ignores everything and starts immediately the server as shown below
2024-06-04 10:04:33,146 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2024-06-04 10:04:33,147 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2024-06-04 10:04:33,148 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2024-06-04 10:04:33,148 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000

Why is the behaviour in runserver and daphne completely different?
